# How to label more breakpoints in Y axis ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: GGPLOT GRAGH LINK]

> question7 %>%   ggplot(aes(x = year, y = n , group = state)) + 
>   geom_point(aes(color = state)) + geom_smooth(method = "loess", formula
>   = y ~ x, level = 1, aes(color=state))+ labs(x = "Year", y = "No Visitors",#lab means labels title = "Number of Visitors by year by
>   state", # title of title making interpretation subtitle = "Yearly
>   comparison trend between NY and CA")

For the Y axis , i would like to label it as **1,2,3,4,5,6... all the way to 45.**

Answer (score 2):

Use `scale_y_continuous()` with the `breaks =` argument.

An example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg))

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(10, 35, 1))

cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: hello , but i would like to set the initial y as 0 also

Comment: `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 45, 1), limits = c(0,45))`